# Can children demand death penalty for father if he murders their mother?

Tags: fiqh, qisas

There was a case where a father killed the mother and the children demanded death sentence for the father. But it was rejected by the court because it said it was violating Islamic Law.

It stated:
"The Islamic jurisprudence stipulates that if a husband has become an heir to the deceased and an heir to the blood after the death of his wife, a son or daughter cannot demand for retribution or revenge for their father."

Can anyone provide evidences for this rule?

Answer (score 3):

No, a person can not seek *Qisas* from their parent (father or mother), and only *Diyyah*, *Tazir* and *Kaffarah* would apply.

The evidence is that causing the death of a parent would be contrary to the obligation of good treatment and respect towards them:

> #### ووصينا الإنسان بوالديه حسنا
>
> And We have enjoined upon man goodness to parents.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 29:8](http://quran.com/29/8)</sup>

> #### وصاحبهما في الدنيا معروفا
>
> but accompany them in [this] world with appropriate kindness
>
> <sup>— [Quran 31:15](http://quran.com/31/15)</sup>

> #### وقضى ربك ألا تعبدوا إلا إياه وبالوالدين إحسانا إما يبلغن عندك الكبر أحدهما أو كلاهما فلا تقل لهما أف ولا تنهرهما وقل لهما قولا كريما واخفض لهما جناح الذل من الرحمة وقل رب ارحمهما كما ربياني صغيرا
>
> And your Lord has decreed that you not worship except Him, and to parents, good treatment. Whether one or both of them reach old age [while] with you, say not to them [so much as], "uff," and do not repel them but speak to them a noble word. And lower to them the wing of humility out of mercy and say, "My Lord, have mercy upon them as they brought me up [when I was] small."
>
> <sup>— [Quran 17:23-24](https://legacy.quran.com/17/23-24)</sup>

Further, the Hadith of the Prophet ﷺ  negates any right of Qisas for the offspring on a parent:

> #### لا يقاد الوالد بالولد
>
> A father is not to be killed for his offspring
>
> <sup>— [Bulugh al-Maram](https://sunnah.com/urn/2114390)</sup>

---

**References:**

- [الفقه الإسلامي وأدلته](https://shamela.ws/book/384/5533#p1) :

  > ومثال كون وارث القصاص من ليس له القصاص من القاتل: أن يقتل أحد الوالدين الوالد الآخر، وكان لهما ولد (ذكر أو أنثى) فيسقط القصاص؛ لأن الولد هو صاحب الحق فيه، ولا يجب للولد قصاص على والده، بدليل أنه لو جنى الوالد على ولده، وقتله، لا يقتص منه؛ للحديث النبوي: «لا يقاد الوالد بالولد» فمن باب أولى لا يقتص للولد من الوالد إذا جنى الوالد على غير ولده
  >
  > [[Prev](https://shamela.ws/book/384/5503)]
  >
  > ألا يكون المجني عليه جزء القاتل، أي ألا تكون هناك رابطة الأبوة والبنوة، فلا قصاص على أحد الوالدين (الأب والجد، والأم أو الجدة وإن علوا) بقتل الولد أو ولد الولد وإن سفلوا، لقوله صلّى الله عليه وسلم: «لا يقاد الوالد بالولد»  ... ولأن في القصاص من الأب شبهة آتية من حديث: «أنت ومالك لأبيك» والقصاص يدرأ بالشبهات. ولأن الأوامر المطالبة بالإحسان إلى الآباء تمنع القصاص منهم، فقد كان الأب سبباً في إيجاد ولده، فلا يكون الابن سبباً في إعدامه
- [الهداية في شرح بداية المبتدي](https://shamela.ws/book/11820/1109#p1)

  > ومن ورث قصاصا على أبيه سقط لحرمة الأبوة

Comment: Can you find a reference for the reason that was given by the court which is in the question?